# Manual coloring of dots by set color in Complex Upset

Tags: r, upsetr, complex-upset

I would like to create an UpSet plot using the [ComplexUpset](https://github.com/krassowski/complex-upset) package. I would like to manually color the dots in the intersection matrix to match the sets' color.

Here's what I've attempted so far:

```
movies <- read.csv( system.file("extdata", "movies.csv", package = "UpSetR"), header=T, sep=";" )

ComplexUpset::upset(movies, colnames(movies)[3:5], name='genre', width_ratio=0.1, 
  matrix=(intersection_matrix(geom=geom_point()) +
            scale_color_manual(values = c('Action'='red', 'Adventure'='blue', 'Children'='yellow'))), 
  queries=list(upset_query(set='Action', fill='red'),
               upset_query(set='Adventure', fill='blue'),
               upset_query(set='Children', fill='yellow')))
```

[image: Output]

Adding scale_color_manual only resulted in an extra legend of dots that was plotted which I do not want. I would like the dots, in the intersection matrix itself, for 'Action' to be red, the dots for 'Adventure' to be blue and the dots for 'Children' to be yellow. The segment line connecting the dots should remain black.

Comment: Forgot to mention, I would like only the 'active' dots to be colored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dots don't change color because you are passing `fill` (not `color`) to `upset_query`; you can keep using `fill` if you like but in that case you need to also change the shape of the dot so that they have area to be filled, which can be done using `shape='circle filled'` (there are other shapes too!).

Similarly, the `scale_color_manual` would not be a perfect choice in plain ggplot2, but given that it is overridden by ComplexUpset it is actually a good idea, but you will need to customize override.aes to make it display as intended.

```
library(ComplexUpset)
library(ggplot2)

upset(
    movies,
    colnames(movies)[3:5],
    name='genre',
    width_ratio=0.1,
    matrix=(
        intersection_matrix(geom=geom_point(shape='circle filled', size=3))
        + scale_color_manual(
            values=c('Action'='red', 'Adventure'='blue', 'Children'='yellow'),
            guide=guide_legend(override.aes=list(shape='circle'))
        )
    ),
    queries=list(
        upset_query(set='Action', fill='red'),
        upset_query(set='Adventure', fill='blue'),
        upset_query(set='Children', fill='yellow')
    )
)
```

[image: Solution with circle filled]

Alternatively, you could simply pass `color` in addition to `fill`, but I think that the `fill` option give nicer visuals.

Comment: Thank you for the solution and for the explanation!! Also thank you for creating this wonderful package! :)